# Scala + MongoDB: optional fields and immutables

Tags: scala, mongodb, immutability, mongo-scala-driver

I have this domain object:

```
case class Person (
  name : String,
  age: Option[Int],
  email : String
) extends MongoObject
```

with the age optional field. So I defined my factory:

```
object Person extends MongoObjectShape[Person] {
  lazy val name = Field.scalar("name", _.name)
  lazy val age = Field.optional("age", t => t.age)
  lazy val email = Field.scalar("email", _.email)

  override lazy val * = name :: age :: email :: Nil
  override def factory(dbo: DBObject): Option[Person] = 
    for {
      n <- name from dbo
      t <- age from dbo
      z <- email from dbo
    } yield new Person(n, t, z)
}
```

but it does not compile, since I get:

```
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required: Option[Int]
[error]     } yield new Person(n, t, z)
[error]                           ^
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe, you could write

```
override def factory(dbo: DBObject): Option[Person] = 
    for {
      n <- name from dbo
      z <- email from dbo
    } yield new Person(n, age from dbo, z)
```

Comment: thank you, it works. Definitely I have to learn more about pattern matching in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

A variant of amsayk's answer, but slightly more symmetrical

```
for {
      n <- name from dbo
      t = age from dbo
      z <- email from dbo
    } yield new Person(n, t, z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap t in a Some object

```
} yield new Person(n, Some(t), z)
```

Comment: that way I will never have the case of None

Comment: Then what amsayk suggested should work as 'age from dbo' will return an option object.